# MySQL find row index position, complex query

Tags: mysql, select, indexing, position, row

I know this been asked many times here, been through most of the posts here, but I can't get it working so thought to ask it again.

**The problem:**
There's a score list, I'm trying to show user what's his/her position in the score list. There's a player_id, user is selected from two tables(players.id, scores.player_id). I've never tried such query, I wrote sth like this based on the instruction given in this site but no luck, this query isn't right, kinda lost here.

```
SELECT 
    @rn:=@rn + 1 AS rank, scores.score
FROM
    (SELECT 
        scores.score, COUNT(*) AS ordercount
    FROM
        scores, players
    WHERE
        players.uid = '$uid'
            AND scores.version = '$version'
            AND scores.lvl = '$lvl'
            AND scores.player_id = players.id
    GROUP BY scores.score
    ORDER BY scores.score DESC) t1,
    (SELECT @rn:=0) t2
```

Result:

```
Unknown column 'scores.score' in 'field list
```

thanks!

Score table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `scores` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `player_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lvl` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `score` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `played_times` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `version` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `scores`

```
INSERT INTO `scores` (`id`, `player_id`, `lvl`, `score`, `played_times`, `version`, `ip`, `timestamp`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 9990, 4, '1', 'xx.xx.xx.xxx', '2012-12-24 01:46:10'),
(2, 1, 2, 5750, 1, '1', 'xx.xx.xx.xxx', '2012-12-24 01:46:49'),
(3, 1, 1, 10290, 5, '1', 'xx.xx.xx.xxx', '2012-12-24 02:47:25'),
(6, 1, 1, 13620, 6, '1', 'xx.xx.xx.xxx', '2012-12-24 10:40:26'),
(7, 2, 2, 241251, 2, '1', 'xx.xx.xx.xxx', '2012-12-24 19:03:22');
```

Player table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `players` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `uid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `scores`

```
INSERT INTO `players` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `pass`, `hash`, `uid`, `ip`, `timestamp`) VALUES
(1, 'Test', 'TEST@TEST.COM', '', '51516h0c0', '7b3bd627c9b0', 'xx.xx.xx.xxx', '2012-12-24 00:56:38');
```

PHP;

```
/*
    get player's topscore position among others
*/
function _getPlayerTopScorePos($uid,$lvl,$version)
{
    $uid            = _jClean($uid);
    $version        = _jClean($version);
    $lvl            = _jClean($lvl);

    include 'db.inc.php';

    $q = mysql_query("SELECT 
        @rn:=@rn + 1 AS rank, t1.score
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            scores.score, COUNT(*) AS ordercount
        FROM
            scores, players
        WHERE
                players.uid = '$uid'
                AND scores.version = '$version'
                AND scores.lvl = '$lvl'
                AND scores.player_id = players.id
        GROUP BY scores.score
        ORDER BY scores.score DESC) t1,
        (SELECT @rn:=0) t2");

    echo mysql_error();

    $x = mysql_fetch_array($q);
    $a = $x["rank"];

    @mysql_close();

    return $a;  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you change the table reference from scores to t1, since you're using an alias to the subquery?

```
SELECT 
        @rn:=@rn + 1 AS rank, t1.score
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            scores.score, COUNT(*) AS ordercount
        FROM
            scores, players
        WHERE
            players.uid = '$uid'
                AND scores.version = '$version'
                AND scores.lvl = '$lvl'
                AND scores.player_id = players.id
        GROUP BY scores.score
        ORDER BY scores.score DESC) t1,
        (SELECT @rn:=0) t2
```

-- edit

```
SELECT COUNT(t1.player_id)
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            scores.player_id
        FROM
            scores
            INNER JOIN players ON scores.player_id = players.id
        WHERE
            players.uid = '$uid'
            AND scores.version = '$version'
            AND scores.lvl = '$lvl'
            AND scores.player_id = players.id
            AND scores.score >= '$score'
        GROUP BY scores.player_id) t1
```

You can do a separate query returning the number of users playing and display ie. 25/100

Comment: Hi Edga, Thanks for the reply.. I've tested your query, it seems like it should work but I've tested by entering better score by another user id to the score list, but still returns rank as 1, where it suppose to be 2. It's not right, because there's a better score on the list by another user, therefore it should display as 2nd instead of 1st. No matter what produces result(=rank) 1. 

$x = mysql_fetch_array($q);
$a = $x["rank"];
echo $a;

result: 1

Comment: Do you get an error from your initial question? It sounds like different problem right?

Comment: There's no error now, but doesn't return the position of the user from the score list. :\

Comment: Can you include (edit your initial question or open a new one) sample of data, tables structures and where `@rn` is declared?

Comment: I've added sample data and php func in the main Q.

Comment: So you want to do the comparison in mysql. Haven't you thought about doing it in PHP instead? Putting results into one array, sorting it and reading the position? I know it doesn't directly answers your question but I'm just brainstorming to maybe find an easier solution. In order to compare result for a user you would have to join to another set of results for all users - this makes me think "why not do it in php?"

Comment: well, when the score list is too big won't that affect the performance of requiring the topscore list position? let's say there are over 10,000 scores added, loading all that into array and finding a position would load a while, especially when there are many requests send. (just thinking how to do this in a good way)

Comment: Eureka! I don't know why I'm complicating it so much.  Why won't you just return the rank by counting how many users have more than the current user - please see my edited answer (it may need some tweaking from your side)

Comment: Oh.. this might work.. let me tweak a bit and will test this now, cheers!

Comment: Wow, excellent solution Edga! Thanks a lot m8, that worked perfectly! =)) Marry X-mas and happy holidays!